# Error running sudo (sudo: unable to resolve host [name]: Connection timed out)

Tags: networking, sudo

Whenever I run a sudo command, I get an error message.

```
jay@ignumtop:~$ sudo true
sudo: unable to resolve host ignumtop: Connection timed out
```

I'm not sure how this is really affecting my computer or anything, but if it's an issue that'll lead to my computer bonking itself, I'd like to know what I can do about it. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect a mismatch between /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname. Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `cat /etc/hosts` and: `cat /etc/hostname` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 23):

This is most likely a case of a mismatch between records in `/etc/hosts` and your hostname in `/etc/hostname`.

Firstly, let's start with `/etc/hostname` and get your actual hostname with the command `cat /etc/hostname` which will output the hostname of your system:

```
foobarbaz
```

(`foobarbaz` is an example of the output).

Next, let's check your `/etc/hosts` file.  You should see something like this from `cat /etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   foobar

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

In this example, you can see 'foobarbaz', the hostname I have on my system, is not in `/etc/hosts`.  So let's add it, edit the line for 127.0.1.1 to include your hostname on it `sudo nano /etc/hosts` will open the `nano` text editor on the command line so you can edit and save the file - note you'll have to wait for the 'timed out' problem to resolve itself again):

```
127.0.1.1   foobar foobarbaz
```

Save the file, then try your `sudo` commands again.  You should no longer see this error.

Answer (score -3):

Add following line to your /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1  ignumtop

For other users,
127.0.0.1  name of the PC.

Comment: This doesn't add value beyond what @thomas-ward already said.