# Installing Apps Queries

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies, gcc

Whenever I install apps from the software center it doesn't install but a shortcut of the app I want to install appears on the bar but not installed and pending.

So I tried installing stuff through terminal .

Example I wanted to install `Gdebi` so I typed

```
sudo apt install gdebi
```

And I got:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host vision
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cpp-5 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
 g++-5 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
 gcc-5 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
 gdebi : Depends: gdebi-core (= 0.9.5.7ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: gksu but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: gnome-icon-theme but it is not going to be installed
 libasan2 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
 libatomic1 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
 libcc1-0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
 libcilkrts5 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
 libgcc-5-dev : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
 libgomp1 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
 libitm1 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
 liblsan0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
 libmpx0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
 libquadmath0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
 libstdc++-5-dev : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
 libtsan0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
 libubsan0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

This happens everytime i install something even for vlc i got the same .Please help.

After resolving host when i tried to install vlc i got this

[sudo] password for nishanthr: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 browser-plugin-vlc : Depends: libvlc5 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
 cpp-5 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
 g++-5 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
 gcc-5 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
 libasan2 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
 libatomic1 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
 libcc1-0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
 libcilkrts5 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
 libgcc-5-dev : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
 libgomp1 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
 libitm1 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
 liblsan0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
 libmpx0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
 libquadmath0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
 libstdc++-5-dev : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
 libtsan0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
 libubsan0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libgles2-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                libgles2
       Depends: libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libsdl-image1.2 (>= 1.2.10) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libva-drm1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libva-x11-1 (>= 1.0.3) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libvlccore8 (>= 2.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libxcb-composite0 but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libxcb-xv0 (>= 1.2) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-samba (= 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error running sudo (sudo: unable to resolve host \[name\]: Connection timed out)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/849394/error-running-sudo-sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-name-connection-timed-out)

Comment: You seem to have unwisely installed software that is *incompatible* with your release of Ubuntu. This typically occurs when you install wrong-version software from some old PPA or other Non-Ubuntu source. Uninstall the non-Ubuntu software and then disable that source.

Comment: How do I Uninstall the non-Ubuntu software and then disable that source ?